# Access the Raspberry Pi image on the SD card

Tags: debian, sd-card, windows

I currently have an SD card with a [non-running](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1108/why-does-my-raspberry-pi-keep-on-rebooting) installation of Debian Squeeze. SSH on this card is enabled. However the system keeps rebooting. I would now like to delete the boot.rc file on the boot partition of the SD card from a Windows computer, but I fail.

Here is the problem: I have a Windows pc with an internal card reader (the only card reader available at the moment). I enter the card and can access it and rename boot.rc or delete it. But when I remove the card and put it back again, the boot.rc is back again or has its old name back. Deleting other files on that image results in the same - no effect. I tried pulling it out of the reader without unmounting and unmounting via the taskbar in the lower right Windows corner.

Could you please explain to me, how I can delete/rename boot.rc on the SD card with a Debian installation? Do I have to follow a special unmounting procedure? Right-clicking the SD card in Windows Explorer has a menu item "SG eject", but that shows no effect.

Comment: You checked the permissions under windows for accessing the SD card and the path & file that you try to delete?

Comment: What version of Debian?

Comment: Debian squeeze, edited into the question. @ikku I do not get an error, when I try to delete the file. It disappears and is magically back, when I take the card out and put it back again.

Comment: Is it an thoroughly used SD card? The nature of SD cards is that they usually fail while writing data or deleting data. This can happen without a notice from the OS, like an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of "repairs" must be carried out under Linux, just because Windows is not reliable and generally too "invasive" for such things.

As suggested in the other answer, a Linux LiveCD could be the fastest solution. My favorite LiveCD/USB distribution is [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html) but [DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/download.html) could be sufficient for you specific case.

A similar solution (if you don't want to burn CDs or write USB pens) is to run a live distro inside a VM, giving to it the exclusive access to your card reader.

For what concerns your specific problem, my guess is that Windows is mounting the SD card filesystem read-only. BTW, Windows can't access `ext2`/`ext3` partitions directly, so if you used an `ext2`/`ext3` driver such as [IFS](http://www.fs-driver.org/) probably you forgot to set its RW permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from Linux LiveUSB/LiveCD and try again...

Comment: Not possible, it is my work computer and it doesn't allow booting from cd or USB...